# Acer 5738Z: sending ^[[[B

Tags: keyboard, boot, acer-aspire

When I start up my laptop, my keyboard sends ^[[[B all the time. This causes the BIOS to show the settings manager. When I close the BIOS manager, GRUB/Linux will start up. Suddenly the screen is filled up with the sequence ^[[[B.

Strangely enough when I press any key, the problem disappears.

Does anyone know why? Or what key sends the sequence ^[[[B ?

Comment: If you swap keyboards, does it make a difference?

Comment: @soandos Not that easy with a laptop.

Comment: ouch, sorry, should read more carefully next time.

Comment: @soandos Thank you for the idea. I hope I can solve the problem without buying a new keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

`^[[B` is the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key. (It's not exactly the same as in your question, but far more likey.)

Answer (score 0):

To find out if this is a hardware or software thing, grab Linux Live CD and try booting from it (assuming you can get to it). If you still see the characters, chances are it's hardware.

I would also make sure your keyboard is clean and the key isn't stuck.